# ETL huge data files from s3 to snowflake

Tags: python-3.x, bigdata, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aws-glue, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to build a pipeline that reads huge files from s3 and dump it into snowflake after some transformation logic. Files in s3 are unstructured with different types and numbers of column.

```
e.g.
clmA|clmB|clmC
clm1|clm2
```

Currently I am reading data using python script dividing the data in two different pandas dataframes (onw with columns clmA|clmB|clmC and another with columns clm1|clm2) and inserting to snowflake tables using pandas `write_pandas` method provided by `snowflake.connector.pandas_tools`.

It works fine but the problem is if any huge file fails I have to read and process that file again from the start. I tried `kinesis Data Stream` which allows me to read and process data in chunks but still doesn't solve above problem.
AWS Glue provide job bookmarks but how can I put data to glue using python and then to snowflake
I am new to Data Engineering, so I would love to hear from the community what the recommended path is.

Comment: We had similar requirement, ie., load CSV files from S3 to snowflake, and for this we had followed this AWS blog, https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/performing-data-transformations-using-snowflake-and-aws-glue/, made some changes and are able to load data successfully from S3 to Snowflake.  You may need to handle differently for JSON files.

Comment: This blog provides steps from snowflake to s3. Plus it does not solve how can I resume the read operation from s3 in case of application failures

Comment: yes correct.  But as I had mentioned, we did some code changes to swap source/target so the glue generate the code appropriately, to write from s3 to a snowflake table.  And we had used glue workflow  wherein you can rerun the job after fixing any data issues, let me see if i can provide some code sample.